# Flutter v1.71 in my machine still using old Android Embedding v1 instead of v2

Tags: android, flutter, android-activity, flutter-dependencies, embedding

I was having some trouble with barcode_scan library with my newly created Flutter project. The barcode camera preview page is open, but once detect the QR the android activity does not return any data to my Flutter code. So what I did is I used another machine (MAC & Window) with same flutter version and tried out the barcode_scan it works. So thats means there is some problem with me flutter project. So I try to debug and compare both working and not working project . I get know that the working flutter project MainActivity.kt and not working flutter project MainActivity.kt having different code. Below is the example.The working project have empty MainActivity.kt. After some reading I get to know its Android embedding v1 and v2. V1 is old android embedding and v2 is latest android embedding. But after Flutter 1.1.2 all the project will be created with v2. But in my machine although I update it to Flutter v1.7.1 it still using v1 . All the new project I created is using v1. Because of this some of the packages is not working . But once I did the manual upgrade from v1 to v2 using this doc (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects), the barcode scanner now works. How to make my flutter new project to use v2 automatically instead of v1. Expert help is needed.

**Working flutter project**

````
```package com.example.u_testing
   import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
   class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
   }
```
````

**Not working project**

`````
```package com.example.testi
   import android.os.Bundle
   import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity
   import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
   class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
   }
  }
 ````
`````

**Flutter project**

````
PS D:\Development\Mobile\Example\test\testAndv1> flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1217], locale en-MY)
    • Flutter version 1.17.1 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision f7a6a7906b (2 weeks ago), 2020-05-12 18:39:00 -0700
    • Engine revision 6bc433c6b6
    • Dart version 2.8.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Thiyraash David\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.8052
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[√] VS Code (version 1.45.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Thiyraash David\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.10.2

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available```
````

Comment: Have you tried to run `flutter clean`?

Comment: I have @mFeinstein ,but still all the new project I created is using v1 instead v2

Answer (score 0):

In your post, you are using `Flutter v1.17.1`. Try to [upgrade](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading) to the [current version of Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases).

Based on the documentation, the deprecation of android v1 embedding app and plugin creation [landed in version: `1.20.0-8.0`](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/android-v1-embedding-create-deprecation#timeline). Check the [release notes](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/release-notes-2.0.0) for [20868](https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/20868).

You might also want to check [this post in medium](https://medium.com/flutter/modern-flutter-plugin-development-4c3ee015cf5a). For some references on the implementation.